# Convergence of EM algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am aware that EM eventually converges. However, I still have some confusions regarding this property:

1: As far as I am aware, HMM, Gaussian mixture model and MCMC can converge and all of them use EM internally. Is this why they can converge?

2: Although with property of convergence, EM algorithm may end up differently depending on the initial parameters. So convergence here does not mean EM algorithm always gets the same results, right?

Comment: Re:1 No, they don't *all* use EM

Comment: The property is that each step of EM increases the value of the likelihood associated with the observed data.

Answer (score 3):

1. HMM can use EM, but typical applications also include Baum-Welch. GMM, k-means typically use it. MCMC is a simulation method, not EM. If EM is in some part of an algorithm, the convergence is sure for that part.
2. EM finds you a local optimum depending on the initial values. If the initials change, you may end up with a different local optimum, and you don't get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment about the logic you'e used for question number 1.

Regarding question number 2: You're correct, convergence here doesn't mean resulting in the same results, especially in the case of EM. Reaching the same result usually implies convexity. However, if you have a positive loss function, and you can ensure that you can reduce the loss function in each iteration, you can guarantee convergence to "something" but not a global optimum. This is exactly the case in EM. I hope that's clear enough.